# py2neo Relationship not callable error

Tags: python, neo4j, relationships, py2neo

I am using py2neo REST API to connect to neo4j version 1.9.5 via a Mac.  I have successfully created three nodes: a, b and c using `graph_db.create()`.  Then I successfully created a relationship "MANAGES" between a and b using: `rel, = graph_db.create(rel((a, "MANAGES",b)))`.  However, when I try to create a "MANAGES" relationship between a and c, using `rel2, = graph_db.create(rel((a, "MANAGES",c)))`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Relationship' object is not callable
```

I have not created any indexes for the nodes or relationships.  Could that be the problem?  Presumably there is no problem assuming a data model where a node may have many relationships of the same type with other nodes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've accidentally done there is to override the py2neo function `rel` with you own relationship variable:

```
rel, = graph_db.create(rel((a, "MANAGES",b)))
 ^                      ^
 |                      |
this             overwrites this
```

So the easy fix is to pick another name:

```
ab, = graph_db.create(rel((a, "MANAGES",b)))
```

After that, your subsequent call should work.